# Averaging across rows of different list elements (corresponding to the correct date)

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I am using the following data at the bottom of the post:

Which is a list and looks like the following:

```
$ALB
               ALB.Close
2018-01-03  0.0019747387
2018-01-04 -0.0119843581
2018-01-05  0.0114531296
2018-01-08  0.0425817277
```

The date is the row names and the data has one column. The `dput` is a list of 4 xts items. I am trying to calculate the average daily returns for all elements in 
the list.

Problem: I have used an `lapply` function to do this however the dates in column x firm y does not match the dates in column x firm z. i.e.

So what I am trying to do is take the average of all rows of each element in the list but with the dates matching. So 2018-01-03 for firm $ALB matches 2018-01-03 for firm XYZ and 2018-01-03 for firm ZYX and so forth.

```
    data <- structure(list(NEM = structure(c(-0.00842110239640803, 0.0110381675545126, 
0.00365259993882328, -0.00104223559295447, -0.00653853495845835, 
0.00601699649189813, 0.0129569058056256, 0.0241650061476553, 
0.00526380454315678, -0.0138453814735109, -0.00533738697486497, 
0.00584422934489304, 0.00480220808119647, 0.0165045006714633, 
0.030531129501433, -0.0194322364333841, 0.00684429470673908, 
-0.0239133048610936, 0.00049877776040308, 0.0101725234068617, 
-0.00370958758165774, -0.0350470752510321, -0.0304830688408675, 
-0.00450744499062772, -0.0160732632594973, -0.0114069134733041, 
0.00408878863343487, 0.00407227396138632, 0.00297579010344462, 
0.0521033389842946, 0.0104579450772659, -0.00764137687058186, 
-0.0185812313720746, -0.00600913638417033, -0.0139862154001982, 
0.0277795116860622, 0.0161521524130164, -0.0226347371914426, 
-0.00626301629698345, -0.00235880066493932, -0.00473438542479299, 
0.00918518476064367, 0.0147804848721527, -0.0300479043544404, 
-0.00106159775015735, 0.00132676152309452, 0.00713442063203917, 
0.0062992595922986, -0.000785289923879162, -0.0233122610170273, 
0.00214184820837104, 0.00213737724970997, -0.00454733965349474, 
0.0243656651363202, -0.0160889659055208, 0.0301187363520592, 
0.0287369054253985, -0.0217950852771689, -0.0165335726069507, 
0.0175579261027234, 0.00510595952293924, -0.011267673339777, 
0.00411205903956713, 0.00715561430020983, 0.000509190432218531, 
-0.0182359997042236, 0.02280685569254, 0.0292118636534737, -0.00592294419187356, 
0.0292702847182396, -0.0043363115087085, -0.000966111197924224, 
-0.00703291358834202, 0.0204752187348691, -0.0141676285280821, 
-0.0070379371567153, -0.00024362440748904, -0.0129951321574184, 
0.00615083745067935, -0.00270170863096153, -0.0342747491780635, 
-0.00178321275674165, -0.000765259570568944, 0.0156965754367158, 
-0.00402716360932454, 0.00553313778953068, 0.0027551927605054, 
-0.000500400316926441, 0.0114457337396914, -0.000742457678300834, 
0, -0.022028451013516, 0.00454548779650876, -0.00834914400915432, 
-0.00509427992824651, 0.00534826189328541, -0.0148415723238795, 
0.0204140538863236, 0.00955263662395689, -0.0133486933625315, 
-0.0130153427571003, 0.00665642507246211, -0.00665642507246211, 
-0.00747717815796456, -0.0101444231918548, 0.00781251379645598, 
0.00284939971118403, -0.00207141446227155, -0.00519754268312278, 
0.00493825558534589, 0.00568773501157915, -0.00232288135618663, 
0.0118161917867807, -0.0195983059852964, 0.000780892899739261, 
-0.0020839289147272, -0.0104849454699258, -0.0248112230467479, 
0.0118153631754492, -0.0126260104077724, 0.00485427058929755, 
-0.00512470454334712, 0.000540686685245539, 0.0190073721078763
), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1530984646.86377, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1514937600, 
1515024000, 1515110400, 1515369600, 1515456000, 1515542400, 1515628800, 
1515715200, 1516060800, 1516147200, 1516233600, 1516320000, 1516579200, 
1516665600, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 1517184000, 1517270400, 
1517356800, 1517443200, 1517529600, 1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 
1518048000, 1518134400, 1518393600, 1518480000, 1518566400, 1518652800, 
1518739200, 1519084800, 1519171200, 1519257600, 1519344000, 1519603200, 
1519689600, 1519776000, 1519862400, 1519948800, 1520208000, 1520294400, 
1520380800, 1520467200, 1520553600, 1520812800, 1520899200, 1520985600, 
1521072000, 1521158400, 1521417600, 1521504000, 1521590400, 1521676800, 
1521763200, 1522022400, 1522108800, 1522195200, 1522281600, 1522627200, 
1522713600, 1522800000, 1522886400, 1522972800, 1523232000, 1523318400, 
1523404800, 1523491200, 1523577600, 1523836800, 1523923200, 1524009600, 
1524096000, 1524182400, 1524441600, 1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 
1524787200, 1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 1525305600, 1525392000, 
1525651200, 1525737600, 1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800, 1526256000, 
1526342400, 1526428800, 1526515200, 1526601600, 1526860800, 1526947200, 
1527033600, 1527120000, 1527206400, 1527552000, 1527638400, 1527724800, 
1527811200, 1528070400, 1528156800, 1528243200, 1528329600, 1528416000, 
1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 1528934400, 1529020800, 1529280000, 
1529366400, 1529452800, 1529539200, 1529625600, 1529884800, 1529971200, 
1530057600, 1530144000, 1530230400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(124L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "NEM.Close")), APD = structure(c(0.0054230610294761, 
0.00383853998919026, 0.00834576528166231, 0.00106804328968479, 
0.0025466743378546, -0.0042084884235436, 0.00957677552553271, 
0.00105840891125997, -0.0201846808881774, 0.0107960728349887, 
-0.00989696291260422, 0.00537801719341413, 0.0047562692434111, 
0.00591367758021732, 0.00710905720589228, 0.0185034832734763, 
-0.0241395692826494, -0.0188999323775549, 0.00973232146774716, 
0.000415789951134116, -0.00942841485306811, -0.0239673950493495, 
-0.0407989286881056, 0.0245787066457064, -0.0126245683224271, 
-0.0347934123400346, 0.0340345694401254, 0.0100073029194245, 
-0.00150408027703453, 0.0114123153471066, 0.0143444570479137, 
0.000183351154084299, -0.00440988636603556, -0.0132853871527763, 
0.0111961828257705, 0.0104027185987574, 0.00709716350577594, 
-0.0111230503019586, -0.0173864308858072, 0.000248796721773026, 
-0.00661261286757764, 0.0217312063016717, 0.00561866637078534, 
0.00200773957271405, 0.0153798332786481, 0.0237754643660715, 
-0.00128663093323045, 0.000292489983610089, -0.0114737339624815, 
0.000591646474051188, 0.00283484716189264, -0.0171310701315903, 
-0.00613824524165274, 0.0034950381119554, -0.0308487516113569, 
-0.0197356845659522, 0.0181835158943731, -0.0144571592047251, 
-0.00284089710236479, 0.00535927654181467, -0.0157173904440819, 
0.0172881865420678, 0.0177348599237384, 0.0121384273835838, -0.0256131130454538, 
0.00168643031611726, 0.0183049203428221, -0.00972914685020854, 
0.00880949499187711, -0.000429385616168787, 0.0149819613809576, 
0.0162488574547721, 0.00136694921348024, -0.00936840106294845, 
-0.00318251080071352, -0.000962771586451083, -0.0127837976988943, 
0.00952768057351072, 0.00433910160697781, -0.00766650708900407, 
-0.0166818877205577, 0.00123167699068283, -0.00493555806473633, 
-0.00782326739082517, 0.0144190256831633, 0.00423042240257221, 
0.000367005151343136, 0.0084044588809018, 0.00423625065011723, 
0.00421838050634271, 0.00282241302469899, -0.00408601100947337, 
0.00276586675581569, 0.00138016284288778, 0.00877591949527634, 
0.00710733254279194, -0.0102625545744335, -0.00430237875599815, 
-0.00540417429867368, -0.00658431212699906, -0.0195844507347802, 
0.00757320365192271, -0.00998649025092302, 0.0131098293640468, 
-6.11123016334147e-05, 0.0081608006169489, 0.0171982656126506, 
-5.95915939323177e-05, 0.00469913727574056, -0.000415450373229653, 
-0.00261563576413248, -0.0114341933756794, -0.00223016278410348, 
-0.00933627895948774, -0.00512945084265493, -0.0234765219141977, 
-0.0124240930176276, -0.00706897380454041, 0.0102369419464123, 
-0.0147849176881039, 0.00064184586815319, -0.00450130647982316, 
0.0055914216924613, -0.00192457722230177), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1530984633.34889, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1514937600, 
1515024000, 1515110400, 1515369600, 1515456000, 1515542400, 1515628800, 
1515715200, 1516060800, 1516147200, 1516233600, 1516320000, 1516579200, 
1516665600, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 1517184000, 1517270400, 
1517356800, 1517443200, 1517529600, 1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 
1518048000, 1518134400, 1518393600, 1518480000, 1518566400, 1518652800, 
1518739200, 1519084800, 1519171200, 1519257600, 1519344000, 1519603200, 
1519689600, 1519776000, 1519862400, 1519948800, 1520208000, 1520294400, 
1520380800, 1520467200, 1520553600, 1520812800, 1520899200, 1520985600, 
1521072000, 1521158400, 1521417600, 1521504000, 1521590400, 1521676800, 
1521763200, 1522022400, 1522108800, 1522195200, 1522281600, 1522627200, 
1522713600, 1522800000, 1522886400, 1522972800, 1523232000, 1523318400, 
1523404800, 1523491200, 1523577600, 1523836800, 1523923200, 1524009600, 
1524096000, 1524182400, 1524441600, 1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 
1524787200, 1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 1525305600, 1525392000, 
1525651200, 1525737600, 1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800, 1526256000, 
1526342400, 1526428800, 1526515200, 1526601600, 1526860800, 1526947200, 
1527033600, 1527120000, 1527206400, 1527552000, 1527638400, 1527724800, 
1527811200, 1528070400, 1528156800, 1528243200, 1528329600, 1528416000, 
1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 1528934400, 1529020800, 1529280000, 
1529366400, 1529452800, 1529539200, 1529625600, 1529884800, 1529971200, 
1530057600, 1530144000, 1530230400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(124L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "APD.Close")), EMN = structure(c(0.0113913374865007, 
0.012092339571212, 0.00619771626157739, 0.00380289262868594, 
-0.00215667349318682, -0.00020560354080601, 0.00256739550524543, 
-0.000718206566551416, -0.00638389736429268, 0.000516373226305156, 
-0.000309763021067333, 0.0133362153685157, -0.00367534881339004, 
0.0019414710423975, 0.00691762684249575, 0.0164894145998007, 
0.0200411370244025, -0.0106122150962742, -0.0120250492493872, 
-0.00843375493576826, -0.00769236594422829, 0.00859936526425997, 
-0.0219990134771564, 0.0194774527325041, -0.000403979803474286, 
-0.0562080205450712, 0.0130596216187238, 0.0282880135035501, 
0.00388911555537863, 0.0182190769120476, 0.00410394454288276, 
0.000199720338255993, 0.00159668731254037, 0.00794517052606381, 
0.00414616590156758, 0.01883441829965, 0.00741633060984537, -0.0184006840659103, 
-0.0120950980361165, -0.00665045857828694, 0.00338035709877893, 
0.0232511868964584, 0.0258461497527342, 0.00320789022694079, 
-0.00245215620982453, 0.0315096373454482, 0.0140827750681725, 
-0.0135339550738403, -0.0171559274542918, -0.00484937071213576, 
0.00763646840438081, -0.0117582728347561, -0.00423308094483144, 
0.0130182028667365, -0.0331093425499462, -0.0113170234040947, 
0.0239330751623026, -0.00275810720872283, -0.0078401778404773, 
0.0133488060214058, -0.0277542176521548, 0.00262579288906473, 
0.00667930460213384, 0.0159834764506135, -0.0237317379749378, 
-0.00155683596687428, 0.0341741791582582, -0.0105961539643813, 
0.0101254710379655, -0.00727616719580837, 0.0174865878733153, 
0.00789049329625602, 0.00203215472593943, -0.00833957745985714, 
-0.00121041867406824, -0.00121181094325618, -0.0179760709107022, 
-0.0014255264608023, 0.00710735032394627, -0.0123517389827379, 
-0.0243866933214081, 0.000587572240058343, 0.00488329913557628, 
0.00223837374136959, 0.0185877162069357, 0.00257299418778789, 
0.00436846850633721, 0.018030331961536, 0.00232396113863231, 
-0.00904724727300543, -0.000187443776902718, 0.00737598231043624, 
0.00999639932918583, -0.000921395049950924, 0.00432318200810933, 
-0.00238922187900936, -0.00230276890220882, -0.005455688782952, 
-0.00539236164836598, -0.00946005279797024, -0.0193848807683992, 
0.00507249972609181, -0.00420934328798506, 0.0139942406699882, 
0.00273779733312818, 0.00282435694963468, 0.0332839999492185, 
-0.0153024287084564, 0.00708469623287566, 0.00302103032876477, 
0.000639639981972806, -0.00926911605846303, -0.0048985633556704, 
0.00913078060620265, -0.0100577180017636, -0.0343397568219022, 
-0.011293059602913, -0.0202977999757152, 0.0112294229586443, 
-0.0175893670426062, -0.000797795989269545, -0.0110354851864178, 
0.00573355709600687, 0.00260444908522839), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1530984636.40539, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1514937600, 
1515024000, 1515110400, 1515369600, 1515456000, 1515542400, 1515628800, 
1515715200, 1516060800, 1516147200, 1516233600, 1516320000, 1516579200, 
1516665600, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 1517184000, 1517270400, 
1517356800, 1517443200, 1517529600, 1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 
1518048000, 1518134400, 1518393600, 1518480000, 1518566400, 1518652800, 
1518739200, 1519084800, 1519171200, 1519257600, 1519344000, 1519603200, 
1519689600, 1519776000, 1519862400, 1519948800, 1520208000, 1520294400, 
1520380800, 1520467200, 1520553600, 1520812800, 1520899200, 1520985600, 
1521072000, 1521158400, 1521417600, 1521504000, 1521590400, 1521676800, 
1521763200, 1522022400, 1522108800, 1522195200, 1522281600, 1522627200, 
1522713600, 1522800000, 1522886400, 1522972800, 1523232000, 1523318400, 
1523404800, 1523491200, 1523577600, 1523836800, 1523923200, 1524009600, 
1524096000, 1524182400, 1524441600, 1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 
1524787200, 1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 1525305600, 1525392000, 
1525651200, 1525737600, 1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800, 1526256000, 
1526342400, 1526428800, 1526515200, 1526601600, 1526860800, 1526947200, 
1527033600, 1527120000, 1527206400, 1527552000, 1527638400, 1527724800, 
1527811200, 1528070400, 1528156800, 1528243200, 1528329600, 1528416000, 
1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 1528934400, 1529020800, 1529280000, 
1529366400, 1529452800, 1529539200, 1529625600, 1529884800, 1529971200, 
1530057600, 1530144000, 1530230400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(124L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "EMN.Close")), LYB = structure(c(0.00026726357085316, 
0.00479873832986488, 0.0138224673640766, -0.00227592881371752, 
0.00907273942528164, -0.00104268842080923, 0.0229460335631657, 
-0.000169912484517809, -0.0153276195757552, 0.00850628505766515, 
8.55712895351246e-05, 0.0255915240519293, -0.00820565602290824, 
-0.00429711236024488, 0.00429711236024488, 0.0150202757101123, 
0.00619248160062913, -0.00478543813577748, -0.0171843232903441, 
0.00829530941280332, -0.0192086618529448, -0.0469332647110745, 
-0.0307800263024287, 0.0453827196503545, -0.0316863766103399, 
-0.041475870113266, 0.0112793470058072, 0.0250139864766936, -0.000547077620046466, 
0.0212966089812676, -0.0182912608788621, -0.012444116917032, 
-0.000184208106196238, 0.00459390754968858, 0.0158243208905242, 
0.00692351819284642, -0.00981499932746299, -0.00772132624631716, 
-0.0132185049972575, -0.000832022241961994, -0.00854466067240356, 
0.0135262301297567, 0.00979816473551764, -0.00328588291462584, 
-9.13737143486415e-05, 0.0262590858104161, -0.0102050837332612, 
-0.00722418726141694, -0.0145148016239043, -0.0118399218108092, 
-0.00270208409127992, -0.0038327039742736, 0.00653478806555352, 
0.0342085486807688, -0.0423368038687348, -0.0194180384009712, 
0.00515163324584478, -0.00908094968259743, -0.00955187922579448, 
0.0242314013075697, -0.0188171272546986, 0.00413760517292339, 
-0.0136319217013581, 0.0204265218421238, -0.0394915839846544, 
-0.0135852752964238, 0.0288466852995617, -0.001271053734337, 
0.0144725757486697, -0.00638481424486415, 0.0144525107894804, 
0.014246608000736, 0.0263381465976602, -0.0117339083085657, 0.000743236756094667, 
0.00592594326754714, -0.0222168941689738, -0.005205169537712, 
0.0103833197889074, 0.00168887264179052, -0.00885123476938166, 
-0.018519066506558, 0.00920692219021024, -0.0076665733582546, 
0.00804837158575289, -0.00181482451938209, -0.000573749659871226, 
0.0500010967574456, 0.0226709601755619, 0.00133341058321257, 
-0.00525493965546708, 0.00169524911580687, 0.0276085766114225, 
0.00760266296948053, 0.000258155843375185, 0.0112086563849667, 
-0.0116389933270629, -0.00439973099503721, 0.0116899474092493, 
-0.0282538510876442, -0.0205149507218252, 0.0215692031523398, 
-0.0155754830126833, 0.0088794756151378, 0.00238396649585759, 
0.0179177366260035, 0.0222726267558109, 0.00422690624921973, 
-0.00380345305494334, -0.00475340010442249, 0.00119046784285448, 
-0.0183538516399846, -0.0120168373425571, 0.0101974822735915, 
-0.00530367719466085, -0.0306272745291913, -0.0112995552539328, 
-0.0181639984003068, 0.0273939708477471, -0.031103806302724, 
0.00629864977064276, 0.0068096148514476, 0.00283893227365883, 
0.00456205179109137), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1530984643.37014, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1514937600, 
1515024000, 1515110400, 1515369600, 1515456000, 1515542400, 1515628800, 
1515715200, 1516060800, 1516147200, 1516233600, 1516320000, 1516579200, 
1516665600, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 1517184000, 1517270400, 
1517356800, 1517443200, 1517529600, 1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 
1518048000, 1518134400, 1518393600, 1518480000, 1518566400, 1518652800, 
1518739200, 1519084800, 1519171200, 1519257600, 1519344000, 1519603200, 
1519689600, 1519776000, 1519862400, 1519948800, 1520208000, 1520294400, 
1520380800, 1520467200, 1520553600, 1520812800, 1520899200, 1520985600, 
1521072000, 1521158400, 1521417600, 1521504000, 1521590400, 1521676800, 
1521763200, 1522022400, 1522108800, 1522195200, 1522281600, 1522627200, 
1522713600, 1522800000, 1522886400, 1522972800, 1523232000, 1523318400, 
1523404800, 1523491200, 1523577600, 1523836800, 1523923200, 1524009600, 
1524096000, 1524182400, 1524441600, 1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 
1524787200, 1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 1525305600, 1525392000, 
1525651200, 1525737600, 1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800, 1526256000, 
1526342400, 1526428800, 1526515200, 1526601600, 1526860800, 1526947200, 
1527033600, 1527120000, 1527206400, 1527552000, 1527638400, 1527724800, 
1527811200, 1528070400, 1528156800, 1528243200, 1528329600, 1528416000, 
1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 1528934400, 1529020800, 1529280000, 
1529366400, 1529452800, 1529539200, 1529625600, 1529884800, 1529971200, 
1530057600, 1530144000, 1530230400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(124L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "LYB.Close"))), .Names = c("NEM", 
"APD", "EMN", "LYB"))
```

EDIT: Using `means <- lapply(returns, function(x) mean(x))` does not give me the desired resuts. (it calculates the column means of each element in the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `merge()` the `zoo` elements in the list. After that it is as simple as running `rowMeans()`.

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)

merged <- do.call(merge, data)
merged.avg <- merge(merged, avg=rowMeans(merged))

print(head(merged.avg), digits=3)

#            NEM.Close APD.Close EMN.Close LYB.Close      avg
# 2018-01-03  -0.00842   0.00542  0.011391  0.000267 0.002165
# 2018-01-04   0.01104   0.00384  0.012092  0.004799 0.007942
# 2018-01-05   0.00365   0.00835  0.006198  0.013822 0.008005
# 2018-01-08  -0.00104   0.00107  0.003803 -0.002276 0.000388
# 2018-01-09  -0.00654   0.00255 -0.002157  0.009073 0.000731
# 2018-01-10   0.00602  -0.00421 -0.000206 -0.001043 0.000140
```

Answer (score 1):

> `lapply` returns a `list` of the same length as `X`, each element of which is the result of applying `FUN` to the corresponding element of `X`. [Refer R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/lapply).

so when you evaluate `mean` over your `data` list:

```
lapply(data , FUN = mean)         # calculates mean for every stock and 
                                  # returns a length of 4

#$NEM
#[1] -9.566582e-05
#
#$APD
#[1] -0.0004911925
#
#$EMN
#[1] 0.0004726381
#
#$LYB
#[1] -0.0001728595
```

It's always better to simplify the *data* in a manner suitable for your analysis. you can use the other function from `apply` *family* to do it, `sapply`:

```
d <- data.frame(sapply(data, FUN = c))        
d['avg'] <- rowMeans(d)

head(d, n = 3)
#              NEM           APD           EMN           LYB           avg
#1   -0.0084211024  5.423061e-03  0.0113913375  2.672636e-04  2.165140e-03
#2    0.0110381676  3.838540e-03  0.0120923396  4.798738e-03  7.941946e-03
#3    0.0036525999  8.345765e-03  0.0061977163  1.382247e-02  8.004637e-03
```

Comment: Notice 1: this will mess up if the time series' don't have the exact same index, 2: will strip attributes and not return a `zoo` object. 1 is not an issue in this specific case, and 2 is only an issue if you care about the attributes (like source and last update in this case) and furter analysis steps don't expect a `zoo` object.